# Output vector given an image for Siamese model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, siamese-network

This page (https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/) highlights how we train a Siamese model. The model will output a score given two images input. What I want to do is that, during inference, given an image, I want it to return a 128-dimension vector that represents the image, how should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you run model.summary() you will see a summary of all model layers. In your case 'model' appears to be the layer of interest. Then you can select the layer that contains the 128D output using the **get_layer()** method. Finally you can extract the output as below.

```
model.get_layer('model').output
```